# Is it possible to predefine the template literal in ECMAScript 6 and reuse many times?

Tags: javascript, string, templates

[template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

For example,

```
//define a template literal
let template = `Hello {target}`;

//Then reuse it, just examples to show the idea
let str1 = Format(template, "World");//str1 becomes "Hello World"
let str2 = Format(template, "There");//str2 becomes "Hello There"
let str3 = Format(template, "There Again");//str3 becomes "Hello There Again"
```

BTW, it's a common practice to reuse template string by [`string.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) in C#:

```cs
string template = `Hello {0}`;
string str1 = string.Format(template, "World");//str1 becomes "Hello World"
string str2 = string.Format(template, "There");//str2 becomes "Hello There"
string str3 = string.Format(template, "There Again");//str3 becomes "Hello There Again"
```

The question is, can it be done with ES6?

Comment: Though stereotypical for SO, the highest voted answer on the dupe target is absolutely horrendous, and one should read the second highest instead.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done similarly by using a function:

```
function GetHelloStr(target){
  return `Hello ${target}`;
}
let str1 = GetHelloStr("World");
let str2 = GetHelloStr("There");
let str3 = GetHelloStr("There Again");
```

But in this case, the template string is not reused. Every call of `GetHelloStr` will create a new string, which isn't performant.

It can be done similarly by [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)

```
function HelloStr(strings, target){
  return `Hello ${target}`;
}
let str1 = HelloStr`${'World'}`;
let str2 = HelloStr`${'There'}`;
let str3 = HelloStr`${'There Again'}`;
```

This also doesn't reuse the template string. I'd rather use the function approach.

Also I found a library which exactly handles such cases:
https://github.com/davidchambers/string-format

Sadly, none of those is elegant as `string.Format` from C#.